# После 15-20 минут сервер перестает отвечть

Tags: hibernate, java-ee, сессия, jsf, transition

Использую HIbernate ,после 5 минут бездействя со стороны юзера сервер перестает отвечать и надо обновитьь страницу.Как это исправить Вот мои конфиги

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">*****</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">////</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">////</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
 <mapping class="entity.Diver"/>
  </session-factory>
```

> > WARN:   SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01 ERROR:   Communications link failure The last packet successfully received from the server was
> >     262,204 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the
> >     server was 0 milliseconds ago. Severe:
> >     org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open
> >     connection    at
> >     org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1431)
> >       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor200.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
> >     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> >     org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:356)
> >       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy209.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)     at
> >     model.Driver_dao.getAll(Driver_dao.java:19)   at
> >     controller.DiverController.getLst(DiverController.java:22)    at
> >     sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor199.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
> >     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> >     javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)     at
> >     com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
> >       at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)   at
> >     com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)    at
> >     com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
> >       at
> >     javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
> >       at
> >     javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
> >       at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)   at
> >     javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1822)   at
> >     javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484)
> >       at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473)    at
> >     javax.faces.component.UIData.iterate(UIData.java:1953)    at
> >     javax.faces.component.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:1176)     at
> >     javax.faces.component.UIForm.processDecodes(UIForm.java:225)  at
> >     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1222)
> >       at
> >     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1222)
> >       at
> >     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:929)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
> >       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
> >     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
> >       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)   at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
> >       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
> >       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> >     com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
> >     Communications link failure The last packet successfully received from
> >     the server was 262,204 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent
> >     successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.    at
> >     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> >       at
> >     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >       at
> >     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> >       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> >       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)     at
> >     com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989)
> >       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3556)     at
> >     com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3456)  at
> >     com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3897)    at
> >     com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)     at
> >     com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)  at
> >     com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)   at
> >     com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4842)
> >       at
> >     com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:912)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:94)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
> >       ... 65 more Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response
> >     from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection
> >     was unexpectedly lost.    at
> >     com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3008)   at
> >     com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3466)  ... 75
> >     more Warning:   /index.xhtml @33,99 value="#{diverController.lst}":
> >     org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully
> >     started javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml @33,99
> >     value="#{diverController.lst}": org.hibernate.TransactionException:
> >     Transaction not successfully started  at
> >     com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
> >       at
> >     javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
> >       at
> >     javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
> >       at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)   at
> >     javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1822)   at
> >     javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484)
> >       at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473)    at
> >     javax.faces.component.UIData.iterate(UIData.java:1953)    at
> >     javax.faces.component.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:1176)     at
> >     javax.faces.component.UIForm.processDecodes(UIForm.java:225)  at
> >     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1222)
> >       at
> >     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1222)
> >       at
> >     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:929)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
> >       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
> >     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
> >       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)   at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
> >       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
> >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
> >       at
> >     org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
> >       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> >     javax.el.ELException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction
> >     not successfully started  at
> >     javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:368)     at
> >     com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
> >       at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)   at
> >     com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)    at
> >     com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
> >       ... 44 more Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException:
> >     Transaction not successfully started  at
> >     org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:202)
> >       at model.Driver_dao.getAll(Driver_dao.java:24)  at
> >     controller.DiverController.getLst(DiverController.java:22)    at
> >     sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor199.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
> >     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> >     javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)     ... 50 more
>
> Severe:   org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not
>   successfully started  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.rollback(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:202)
>     at model.Driver_dao.getAll(Driver_dao.java:24)  at
>   controller.DiverController.getLst(DiverController.java:22)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor199.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>     at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)   at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)    at
>   com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1822)   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:484)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:473)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIData.iterate(UIData.java:1953)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:1176)     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIForm.processDecodes(UIForm.java:225)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1222)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1222)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:929)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: кто перестает отвечать?

Comment: Response error был

Comment: кто перестает отвечать? tomcat? glassfish? что в логах?

Comment: ааа извините щас